# LinearLayout with 4 images--i cant see them hole

Tags: android

I have a linear layout with 4 images with horizontal orientation. My problem is that the first image is cropped and i cant see both of them in my galaxy s,only in some emulators..any help please?this is my linear layout code:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >  



        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header_new_3"   
            android:layout_weight="1"
                 />  


        <ImageButton   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header_btn1"                          
               />  

        <ImageButton        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header_btn2"                   

            />

        <ImageButton  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header_btn3"                           

            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is what i want  [image]

and this is what i get  [image]

@Jamo:  image1:

[image]

image2,3,4:

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the images to help in testing?

Comment: of course,just a second to upload them

Answer (score 0):

Your containing layout is `fill_parent`, meaning it's restricted to the width of its parent (probably the whole screen). Each `ImageButton` is set to width `wrap_content`, meaning it just fits the width of its content. If the widths of the backgrounds of the images you're using sum up to more than the total parent width, you're going to have problems. This seems to be what's happening. You can't fit more pixels into a screen than what you have.

**Update:**

With your provided graphics, the "hello" image is 138px and the star is 60px. 138 + 60 * 3 = 318. If your screen is 480px wide (I think the Galaxy S is 480 wide) then you should be able to fit. If you put these into the default or mdpi folder (and the Galaxy S is hdpi) then these will be scaled to 1.5x that, which is 477px. That should still fit.

Comment: so the only way to fix it is to have smaller graphics?

Comment: I've updated with some quick calculations. Is the `LinearLayout` really the top level layout? or is it contained within something else?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to create something similiar is to use RelativeLayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/iv4" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv4" 
        android:id="@+id/iv3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv3" 
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv2" 
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

We chatted about this in a previous question.  Please post the whole layout file.  The layout_weight won't do much, as hinted at in other posts, if the total width is being constrained by whatever is the parent of the outer LinearLayout.

Also, some thoughts.

You have "fill_parent" for the ImageView heights.  I think those should be "wrap_content".  You're setting the images with 'background' rather than 'src', which is kind of weird.

Also, that first image should be in another layout container, to allow stretching that doesn't screw up the 'hello'.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >  


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/header_new_3"   
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Not 100% sure on that being exactly what you want, but the ultimate goal would be to stretch the first image without shearing it in any way.